# Adding/selecting fields to/from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've an RDD lets say `dataRdd` with fields like `timestamp` ,`url`, ...

I want to create a new RDD with few fields from this `dataRdd`.

Following code segment creates the new RDD, where `timestamp` and `URL` are considered values and not field/column names:

```
var fewfieldsRDD= dataRdd.map(r=> ( "timestamp" -> r.timestamp , "URL" ->   r.url))
```

However, with below code segment, `one`, `two`, `three`, `arrival`, and `SFO` are considered as column names.:

```
val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")
val numairRdd= sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports))
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I create a new Rdd with field names mapped to values from another Rdd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an RDD of tuples, not `Map` objects. Try:

```
var fewfieldsRDD= dataRdd.map(r=> Map( "timestamp" -> r.timestamp , "URL" ->   r.url))
```